# Excel Unusual behaviour: hiding ribbon also hides TITLE bar if application is invisible

Tags: excel, vba

I’m creating a custom application, which will launch in its own separate instance of Excel (new application).

Newly-created instances are invisible by default, and therefore one needs to make them visible manually. I like to make my application visible only after everything is set up – to avoid screen flicker. I see this as a sleeker solution than turning off and on ScreenUpdating: i.e if the application is invisible anyway, then there should be no need to switch ScreenUpdating. You can just leave it invisible until you’re ready.

However, I have come across some unusual behaviour with regards hiding the ribbon. The following command:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro ("SHOW.TOOLBAR(" & Chr(34) & "Ribbon" & Chr(34) & ",False)")
```

... is used to hide the ribbon. The effects of this can be seen if the command is simply pasted into the Immediate window. It hides the ribbon: but otherwise the application window is unaffected. BUT... if the application is invisible at the time this command is executed, it appears that not only the ribbon is hidden – but the whole title bar for the window also! Test this in the following sub:

```
Sub TestVisible()
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    xl.Workbooks.Add ' Required
    ' xl.Visible = True ' Un-comment out this line to preserve the Title bar
    ' If the following command is executed while Visible=False, then the TITLE bar will ALSO be hidden alongside the ribbon.
    xl.ExecuteExcel4Macro ("SHOW.TOOLBAR(" & Chr(34) & "Ribbon" & Chr(34) & ",False)") ' Hide the ribbon
    xl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

So my question is: Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour? Is it a bug? If so, is it known about? If it’s not, then is there a solution? (Aside from the workaround of simply making the application visible before the ribbon is hidden, and then setting ScreenUpdating where needed.)

Comment: These days the preferred way to hide the ribbon (or any individual components of the ribbon) is by defining the CustomUI.xml / RibbonUI and a `getVisible` callback.  I'm going to question the design decision about creating new instances of Excel application -- is that related to this question, like, the reason you're doing new instances is so that you can use this legacy method to hide the ribbon?

Comment: That's similar but definitely not identical functionality. I note that the `ExecuteMso` method will also hide the window title @BrakNicku

Comment: @DavidZemens you are right, something went wrong in my test, I will delete previous comment.

Comment: I need a new app in a separate process in order to be able to set `Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests=True` (and set it back to False before quitting). This ensures that if the user happens to open another Excel item while the app is running, it won't open as a workbook within the same custom app - which has all kinds of restrictions set, and would confuse the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent more time on this than I ought to have :) but here are a few workarounds and also what I think is a complete solution in that it restores the "Title" bar to the new Excel instance.

I can speculate about "why" `ExecuteExcel4Macro` doesn't really work properly here:

`ExecuteExcel4Macro` is really a legacy thing that goes back to pre-1995 Excel. It's not often used, and I'd gather that a great deal of those functions don't work anymore. Using that to hide the Ribbon menu bar -- which didn't exist until 2007, and which represented a paradigm shift over the legacy `Application.CommandBars` that were fully exposed to VBA (*example: you cannot do `Application.CommandBars("some command bar name").Visible = False` like you could in Excel <= 2003*) -- seems likely to have some bugs that Microsoft will probably never address.

One interesting thing I found through further investigation using various WinAPI functions is that the `FindWindow` function returns 0 when the Excel is not visible. I might've done something wrong but if not, then I'm guessing this is somehow contributing to the behavior you observe.

## Workarounds (if you're not comfortable with WinAPI)

This is a *similar* approach, but the ribbon is just minimized and can still be toggled by the user:

```
Sub TestAlternate()
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    xl.Workbooks.Add ' Required
    xl.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("HideRibbon")
    xl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

ANother possible workaround adapting your original code would be to force the new instance to be Minimized (and visible) to avoid the buggy behavior with the title bar:

```
Sub TestVisible()
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    xl.Workbooks.Add ' Required
    xl.Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    xl.Visible = True ' Un-comment out this line to preserve the Title bar
    ' If the following command is executed while Visible=False, then the TITLE bar will ALSO be hidden alongside the ribbon.
    xl.ExecuteExcel4Macro ("SHOW.TOOLBAR(" & Chr(34) & "Ribbon" & Chr(34) & ",False)") ' Hide the ribbon
    xl.Visible = False
    xl.Application.WindowState = xlNormal

    ' any additional code required to set up/configure the new instance/application


    xl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

A third possible solution as mentioned in comments on OP, I'd suggest refactoring the code to Add a new workbook from a Template. That Template would contain the CustomUI XML specifications and appropriate VBA callback functions to hide the items on the ribbon. I'm not 100% sure you can fully replicate your design intents with this method, and it's not a trivial thing to do for a first-timer, but it might be worth exploring.

---

## Hiding the Ribbon With WinAPI Call

I found [this solution](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/6148-possible-hide-excel-title-bar.html) which was promising but the implementation was more complicated than I had expected, but I *think* I have something that works for your purposes, modified from the aforementioned.

In the debugging I did, it seems like the Ribbon and the Title bar are very much linked together, you'll notice that I don't use `ExecuteExcel4Macro` at all, as this function call takes care of the ribbon, too. I suspect this linkage may contribute to your original problem!

Here are the API hooks:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Const GWL_STYLE = (-16)
Private Const WS_CAPTION = &HC00000
Private Const WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = &H10000
Private Const WS_MINIMIZEBOX = &H20000
Private Const WS_SYSMENU = &H80000

Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
    ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, _
    ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Enum ESetWindowPosStyles
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40
    SWP_HIDEWINDOW = &H80
    SWP_FRAMECHANGED = &H20
    SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
    SWP_NOCOPYBITS = &H100
    SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
    SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = &H200
    SWP_NOREDRAW = &H8
    SWP_NOREPOSITION = SWP_NOOWNERZORDER
    SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
    SWP_NOZORDER = &H4
    SWP_DRAWFRAME = SWP_FRAMECHANGED
    HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
End Enum

Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Sub ShowTitleBar(xlApp As Excel.Application, bShow As Boolean, Optional bCaptionOverride As Boolean = True)
Dim lStyle As Long
Dim tRect As RECT
'Dim sWndTitle As String
Dim xlhnd

'## I modified this function to receive an Application instance and
'## to use it's .Hwnd property rather than the FindWindow API call
xlhnd = xlApp.hwnd

'// Get the window's position:
GetWindowRect xlhnd, tRect

If Not bShow Then
    lStyle = GetWindowLong(xlhnd, GWL_STYLE)
    lStyle = lStyle And Not WS_SYSMENU
    lStyle = lStyle And Not WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
    lStyle = lStyle And Not WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    '## I added this logic to ensure the CAPTION may always displayed if bCaptionOverride
    If Not bCaptionOverride Then
        lStyle = lStyle And Not WS_CAPTION
    Else
        lStyle = lStyle Or WS_CAPTION
    End If
Else
    lStyle = GetWindowLong(xlhnd, GWL_STYLE)
    lStyle = lStyle Or WS_SYSMENU
    lStyle = lStyle Or WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
    lStyle = lStyle Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    lStyle = lStyle Or WS_CAPTION
End If

SetWindowLong xlhnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle

xlApp.DisplayFullScreen = Not bShow

'// Ensure the style is set and makes the xlwindow the
'// same size, regardless of the title bar.
SetWindowPos xlhnd, 0, tRect.Left, tRect.Top, tRect.Right - tRect.Left, _
    tRect.Bottom - tRect.Top, SWP_NOREPOSITION Or SWP_NOZORDER Or SWP_FRAMECHANGED

End Sub
```

And here is our new sub to hide the ribbon, tested in Excel 2016:

```
Sub Test()
Dim xl As New Excel.Application

xl.Workbooks.Add
ShowTitleBar xl, False

' configure the application

xl.Visible = True

' Re-enable the ribbon, or the user can double-click the title bar or Restore menu.
ShowTitleBar xl, True
End Sub
```

I break after the `Visible = True` statement and confirm the Ribbon is not displayed:

[image]

Finally, at the end of the procedure we can restore the ribbon (if desired)

[image]

---

**NOTE:** I notice is that the "Restore" option in the menu (right-click the Excel Icon in the title bar) does **not** restore the Ribbon if you use `ExecuteExcel4Macro`, but it *does* restore the Ribbon if you use the WinAPI calls.

[image]

If you're merely setting up an environment, then this shouldn't matter, but the method I've implemented doesn't replicate that functionality exactly. It may be possible to further configure that via WinAPI (for instance, I know you can remove that menu from the Title Bar with `lStyle = lStyle And Not WS_SYSMENU`

Comment: Re: TestAlternate - `ExecuteMso ("HideRibbon")` results in an error (Invalid procedure call or argument). `MinimizeRibbon` works, but it's not what I'm after. The `ExecuteExcel4Macro` method is the only one that works. Re: TestVisible - minimising the WindowState  is just another workaround, and doesn't get to the bottom of why the title bar behaviour alters whether the app is visible or not - but thanks anyway.

Comment: My "thanks anyway" was not intended as condescending, so sorry if you took it as such. It was a genuine appreciation of an attempt to help. I'm on Office 2010 (v14), so maybe the HideRibbon isn't implemented in that version. It's not that I have a particular aversion to `ScreenUpdating`, it's just that I know there are workarounds but really want to understand the buggy behaviour as per my question - that's all.

Comment: I have a genuine solution for this :)  give me a moment to type it up for you. I'm not sure I have a total answer about "why" it's behaving this way, though I might have some guesses.

Comment: might've spoken too soon... swear I had it working, now it's not. back to the drawing board.

Comment: Sounds like my own development efforts.. especially when testing between home (Excel 2010) and work (Excel 2007) :)

Comment: @ChrisMelville see revised answer with WinAPI calls. This is working entirely without ExecuteExcel4Macro on my end (Excel 2016).

Comment: wow, that's fantastic. Thank you so much. You definitely deserve a tick. This works in Excel 2010... and as a bonus, it also removes the min/restore/max & [X] close buttons on the window, so the user has to elegantly exit via my commandbuttons. Thanks :)